# How to auto increment on a specific child on firebase based another data

Tags: java, android, firebase, increment

I am using a Firebase Realtime database. I want to increment a number every time I create a data. However, I want to base it from another data. Example Year is 2000 then it will 2000-1. Then another data is 2000 it will be 2000-2. Then if the year is 2001 it will be 2001-1 since it is a different year. I want to increment the numbers. However, I want the number to restart if it has another year.

idReg:
1

idYear:
2000

newDate:
September 16, 2000

```
    etIdYear.setEnabled(true);
    setNewIdYear = newDate.substring(newDate.length() - 4);
    etIdYear.setText(setNewIdYear);
    newIdYear = Integer.parseInt(setNewIdYear);
    newIdReg = Integer.parseInt(setNewReg);

    mCustom = new Custom(newIdYear, newIdReg, newDate);

    key = mDatabase.child("Custom").push().getKey();
    mDatabase.child(newDate).setValue(mCustom);
```

I am still new to this, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "Year is 2000 then it will 2000-1"? So you want to be added in the database `2000-1` as a String or `1999` as a number?

Comment: Let say I  added a date on the database which is September 16, 2000. I took the year since it is a String and put it on the idYear data which is 2000. Then I want to increment it by 1 which will be 2000-1(ignore the dash as part of the data) . Suppose I add another data, date is October 01, 2000. I do the same thing and increment the number which will be 2000-2. Then there is another date which is January 12, 2001. I want to it to be 2001-1 since it is another year. I want to increment the numbers. However, I want the number to restart if it has another year. I apologize if it is confusing.